# Using Yao's principle to find a lower bound

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, lower-bounds, xor

This is a HW question, so I'm not expecting any answers, just a general guidance/help.

Definition. Given $\underset{\neq0}{\underbrace{s}}\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}$, a function $f:\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}\to\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}$ will be called **s-difference-preserving** if for all $x,y\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}$ s.t. $x\neq y$: $x\oplus y=s\iff f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$ (where $\oplus$ is the bitwise xor operation).

Given a difference-preserving (that is, there exists such s so it is s-difference-preserving) function $f$, we talk about algorithms that find such $s$.

We need to prove that every such random (las-vegas) algorithm worst case (w.c. input) average (on the randomness of the algorithm) complexity is $\Omega\left(\sqrt{2^{n}}\right)$.
Where by complexity, we talk about **query-complexity**. That is, how many times we need to query f, to find a value for an input $x$ - that is, find $f\left(x\right)$.

What I know and tried so far:

I assume this is a classic problem for [Yao's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_principle).
So I want to find a distribution, and an optimal deterministic algorithm for it (optimal on average, on that distribution), such that its query-complexity is \Omega\left(\sqrt{2^{n}}\right) on average on that distribution.

Given an $s$, it's easy to create an s-difference-preserving function, since any $s$ defines a partition of pairs on $\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}$. So we just need to choose a different value for every pair $x,y$ s.t. $x\oplus y=s$.

I also know $f\left(0\right)=f\left(s\right)$, and that to find $s$ for a fuction, it's enough to find a pair $x,y$ s.t. $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$, and then calculate $x\oplus y$.

I thought of defining $\forall i\in\left[\sqrt{2^{n}}\right]:\ s_{i}=i\cdot\sqrt{2^{n}}-1$. And create $s_{i}$-difference-preserving function $\forall i\in\left[\sqrt{2^{n}}\right]$.

Define a uniform distribution on them and have the deterministic algorithm check the values of every $s_{i}$. This is done in $\sqrt{2^{n}}$ queries on average.
 But I don't know how to prove this algorithm is optimal for that distribution. Furthermore, I suspect it isn't, since then I would be able to do the same with $s_{i},\ \forall i\in\left[2^{n}\right]$ and “prove” a lower bound of $2^{n}$ which is probably not true.

I would love any help with this.
Also, not as part of the HW, but because I'm interested (these are questions we don't need to submit a solution to), can you think of any deterministic algorithm for the general problem? can you think of any monte carlo random algorithm (with 0.5 chance of success)?

I hope this is not too long, and written clearly enough. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists a Las Vegas algorithm $A^f$ asking $q(n)=o\big(2^{n/2}\big)$ queries. Let $Q_f\subseteq\{0,1\}^n$ be the random variable which denotes the set of queries raised by the algorithm with oracle $f$.

Sample $f$ from the uniform distribution over the collection of all difference preserving functions, and choose $s\in\{0,1\}^n$ uniformly at random, both independently from your algorithm's coins. Let us now ask what is the probability that there exists $g,g':\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^n$ such that $g,g'$ agrees with $f$ on $Q_f$, $g$ is $s$-difference preserving, and $g'$ is not. We denote this probability by $p_A$. Note that if $p_A>0$ then your algorithm cannot respond correctly on all inputs, since there exists $f,s$ such that $f|_{Q_f}$ has both $s$-preserving and non $s$-preserving extensions.

If $f|_{Q_f}$ does not have an $s$-preserving extension, then either there exists $x\in Q_f$ such that $x\oplus s\in Q_f$, or we have $x,y\in Q_f$ with $f(x)=f(y)$. For the first case, Note that $x\oplus s$ is uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}^n$ and independent of $Q_f$, thus the probability that there exists such $x$ is bounded by $\sum\limits_{x\in Q_f}\frac{|Q_f|}{2^n}\le\frac{q^2(n)}{2^n}=o(1)$. A similar bound is obtained for finding a collision for a random $f$ (the preimage of any element in the range of $f$ is of size 2). Additionally, $f$ is not $s$ preserving with probability $\ge\frac{1}{2^n}$, so we can also (with high probability) find a non $s$ difference preserving extension for $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure why there exists such an $x\in Q_{f}$ if $f|_{Q_{f}}$ doesn't have the extension. What about the case where there exists $x,y\in Q_{f}$ s.t. $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$ but $x\oplus y\neq s$ ?

Comment: Also, unless I'm mistaken, that $f|_{Q_{f}}$ extension that is not s-preserving, should be still preserving for another s, as our algorithms only receive preserving functions, and need to find their s.

Comment: I edited to make $f$ random as well, which should answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still wondering. If there exists $x,y\in Q_{f}$ s.t. $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$ we can't extend it for any s. What if $Q_{f}$ always contain such elements? In fact, it seems to me almost a requirement for the algorithm to decide...

Comment: And I'm still not sure how to show that that "non s preserving extension" is indeed preserving for another s. (which is needed since the algorithm only works on preserving functions).

Comment: Since $f$ is random, you can upper bound that probability that $Q_f$ contains $x,y$ with $f(x)=f(y)$. The bound is again $q^2/2^n$, I leave the details for you. Regarding your second question, $f$ is preserving for some $s'$, with high probability $s'\neq s$.

Comment: I don't mean to be ungrateful or anything, I'm just not sure I agree with the  proof (or perhaps I'm not smart enough to understand it).



f is not completely random. It has to be preserving since the input for the alg is always preserving. Thus random out of all the preserving functions. Qf is also not completely random. It depends on f and on the algorithm.
I'm pretty sure the probability to get x,y in Qf s.t. f(x)=f(y) is 1 and not <1.



The proof would work if no such x,y exist in Qf. But since Qf is dependent on f, I don't agree with your upper bound...

Comment: $f$ is a random difference preserving function. Think of it as choosing $u\in\{0,1\}^n$ at random and then choosing, for each $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, a random value for $f(x),f(x\oplus u)$. Let $Q_f^i$ where $1\le i\le q(n)$ be the set of the first $i$ queries raised by the algorithm, and let $j$ be the minimal index such that $Q_f^j$ contains a collision. Note that $Q_f^{j-1}$ is independent of $u$, hence the probability of hitting $x\oplus u$ for some $x\in Q_f^{j-1}$ in the $j$'th iteration is bounded by $\frac{|Q_f^{j-1}|^2}{2^n}$.